# It won't let me run selenium code in IntellJ all of a sudden

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I was going to execute my code, which is the one I always execute every day for my tests, but suddenly this error appears and I have hardly found a solution, I don't know if it is possible that you can help me with that, I attach the response from the console

```
        Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.27 (df4a85108ffad4dca2c409c52f24df7ec0204b91-refs/branch-heads/5005_22@{#4}) on port 33567
    Only local connections are allowed.
    Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
    ChromeDriver was started successfully.
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
    Current browser version is 101.0.4951.54 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'DESKTOP-V4H61F7', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.2'
    Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x003B2733+2434867]
        Ordinal0 [0x003407A1+1968033]
        Ordinal0 [0x0022C678+837240]
        Ordinal0 [0x0024CAC3+969411]
        Ordinal0 [0x002486DA+952026]
        Ordinal0 [0x00245F91+941969]
        Ordinal0 [0x002790B0+1151152]
        Ordinal0 [0x00278D0A+1150218]
        Ordinal0 [0x00274256+1131094]
        Ordinal0 [0x0024E840+976960]
        Ordinal0 [0x0024F736+980790]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00623C72+2515426]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0061702F+2463135]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0045522A+620442]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00454016+615814]
        Ordinal0 [0x0034707B+1994875]
        Ordinal0 [0x0034B938+2013496]
        Ordinal0 [0x0034BA25+2013733]
        Ordinal0 [0x00354DE1+2051553]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7632FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E87A7E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77E87A4E+238]
    
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1002)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
        at Selenium.pruebas_activity21.main(CrearOT.java:28)
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I hope you can help me with it. It doesn't say any relevant changes, but it seems that any code I'm trying to do can no longer be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here, all of the sudden this error. Was running fine on chrome 105 with compatibility warning of 103. Tried to downgrade Chrome, did not help.
Eventually, downloaded the [driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) of 105 and put the chromedriver.exe into ./src/test/resources/drivers folder overwriting the old file
Solved for me

Comment: Hello! I need to update this error, what I had to do is install a new version of chrome driver, in case it does not work, it would be to reinstall IntellIj and chrome driver, and install all the plugins again of selenium